# Understanding the python syntax

Tags: python

Can somebody please help with the below code snippets?

1. `(e, x), y = d`
2. `yhat = atom_count @ w + b`
3. `baseline_val_loss = [0.0 for _ in range(epochs)]`

I am looking for verbal explanations of the above three lines as I never saw those syntaxes in shell scripting. The code I am learning is part of a book located at https://dmol.pub/applied/QM9.html

Comment: You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Comment: The only one that might be hard to look up in all fairness is the `@` which is a matrix multiplication, that I didn't even know was a built in operator until just now.

Comment: The 3rd one is just list comprehension - https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

Comment: Interestingly enough, the last one can also be rewritten without a list comprehension: `baseline_val_loss = [0.0] * epochs`

Comment: in the description for [ml] tag `For MACHINE-LEARNING use [machine-learning] tag PLEASE.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(1)** `(e, x), y = d`

What you are doing here is essentially **unpacking** the values from the variable `d` into the tuple `(e, x)` and the variable `y`. This only works if `d` is in the same format of the left-hand side.

For instance, suppose `d = ((3, 3), 4)`. Then:

```py
d = ((3, 3), 4)
(e, x), y = d

print(e) # prints 3
print(x) # prints 3
print(y) # prints 4
```

Simpler examples would be:

```py
a, b = 2, 3
print(a) # prints 2
print(b) # prints 3

(x, y, z) = (10, 20, 30)
print(x) # prints 10
print(y) # prints 20
print(z) # prints 30
```

The only difference is that in your example you are using a tuple, thus you need to unpack all values correctly.

**(2)** `yhat = atom_count @ w + b`

The `@` operator is an operator used for matrix multiplication, added in Python 3.5.

Here you are essentially declaring a variable `yhat` that is equal to the matrix multiplication of the matrices `atom_count` and `w+b`. For instance:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
])

B = np.array([
    [4, 5],
    [6, 7]
])

print(A @ B) # prints [[19 22]
             #         [43 50]]
```

**(3)** `baseline_val_loss = [0.0 for _ in range(epochs)]`

This is called **list comprehension**. It is a way to initialize lists instead of writing verbose `for` loops. Here you are initializing a list called `baseline_val_loss` with an amount of `epochs` zeros.

If you have `epochs = 10`, then you would have a python list with 10 zeros. The `range` function creates a list from 0 to `epochs - 1`. You can use `_` as variable to iterate because you simply do not care about the current loop value; you won't do anything with it.